# Aligning images vertically center

Tags: css, user-interface, stylesheet

I am very new to CSS. I have recently created a custom front page of my website, but images are not at aligned to the middle (vertically)

I know it should be very small change but could not figure out how to make this work. Please have a look at my homepage and suggest what should I change.

My homepage here -www.dealschintu.com

What I have already tried:

Tried adding tags

```
 vertical-align: middle;
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of vertically centering elements in css. A quick one that could work (depending on how your document is built up) is the following css snippet:

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

You could also try adding `display: table;`
To the parent element, and

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

To the image element.